# Why Image is not getting updated on my React project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, web, portfolio

I am making a react portfolio website and running it on local server 3000 with npm.
For this image it is showing this strange behaviour.

Other images are being shown without a problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH3TS.png) The code is also good as other images are fine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR2dU.png)
The file structure and file names are as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxo6J.png)

Answer (score 0):

The image path you have entered seems to be wrong here.

Try changing the image path as mentioned here => [image]